# Add menu Item in Context menu for particular user

Tags: registry, contextmenu

my program is a specialized copy folder program which move folder to certain location and delete the folder tree in one go using the context menu of explorer which i had created in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory

but the problem is that it is applicable for all the users in the computer, but i have to only show this item in the context menu to particual users, so i guessed that instead of writing the key in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT i have to write it in HEKY_CURRENT_USERS, but i am failed till date, i want this context menu to be available to only particular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The per user classes can be found in the HKCU hive at this location.  Make your changes here and they should only apply to that user.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes
```